# Google Sites picture in html

Tags: html, image, caching, base64, google-sites

I have an issue with Google Sites. A user made a site based on embed html, in which we have clickable pictures.
[site picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e60x.png)

The issue is, the pictures are not visible for everyone. It seems that there is a cache issue for some users but not all of them. They have to constantly delete their cache or using incognito mode  to access them.

I tried as a workaround to encode the pictures in base64 and adding hmtl tags to prevent the cache to be updated. It worked for some but not everyone.

Here the code from the beginning to the first picture to show :

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

<body>

<table align="middle" width="100%" border="4" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolor=#008AC9>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" align="middle" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="4">U-Shin Country</font></th>
    <th rowspan="2" align="middle" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="4">U-Shin Location</font></th>
    <th rowspan="2" align="middle" width="2%"><font face="Arial" size="4">Mft</font></th>
    <th colspan="3" align="middle" width="15%"><font face="Arial" size="4">QMS<br>ISO 9001:2015</font></th>
    <th colspan="3" align="middle" width="15%"><font face="Arial" size="4">QMS<br>IATF 16949:2016</font></th>
    <th colspan="3" align="middle" width="15%"><font face="Arial" size="4">EMS<br>ISO 14001:2015</font></th>
    <th colspan="3" align="middle" width="15%"><font face="Arial" size="4">OHSAS<br>18001:2007<br>ISO 45001</font></th>
    <th colspan="3" align="middle" width="15%"><font face="Arial" size="4">TISAX</font></th>
    <th colspan="3" align="middle" width="15%"><font face="Arial" size="4">EM<br>ISO 50001:2018</font></th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <th align="middle" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Certificate</font></th>
    <th align="left" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Valid from ...</font></th>
    <th align="right" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Until ... </font></th>
    <th align="middle" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Certificate</font></th>
    <th align="left" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Valid from ...</font></th>
    <th align="right" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Until ... </font></th>
    <th align="middle" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Certificate</font></th>
    <th align="left" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Valid from ...</font></th>
    <th align="right" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Until ... </font></th>
    <th align="middle" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Certificate</font></th>
    <th align="left" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Valid from ...</font></th>
    <th align="right" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Until ... </font></th>
    <th align="middle" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Certificate</font></th>
    <th align="left" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Valid from ...</font></th>
    <th align="right" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Until ... </font></th>
    <th align="middle" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Certificate</font></th>
    <th align="left" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Valid from ...</font></th>
    <th align="right" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">Until ... </font></th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="middle" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">BRAZIL</font></td>
    <td align="left" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2"><B>U-Shin do Brasil Sistemas Automotivos Ltda.</B></font></td>
    <td align="middle" width="2%">&#x25A3</td>
    <td align="middle" width="5%"></td>
    <td align="middle" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">&nbsp</font></td>
    <td align="middle" width="5%"><font face="Arial" size="2">&nbsp</font></td>
    <td align="middle" width="5%">
      <a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=spreadsheetlink">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,imageencodedinbase64 title="Brazil (Guarulhos) QMS Certificate" height="42">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Has someone ever experienced this?

The support helped me but couldn't find an answer so I'm trying here.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Then [edit] the question to include a [mre] of the code used to show the images.